# Combinating fixed and fluid elements - tableless

Tags: css

I want to combine a fixed and a fluid element. With `<table>` it is very easy, but I want **tableless**.

With `table`: **http://jsfiddle.net/Tam7z/**

But, how do this without tables, just with `divs` and `CSS`?

HTML:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
<td width="80" class="a">FIXED</td>
<td class="b">FLUID</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { background: #f4f4f4 }
.a { background: #CCC }
.b { background: #999 }

/* */
* { font-family: sans-serif }
td { padding: 5px }
p { color: #CCC; font-style: italic; margin-top: 40px; font-weight: 100 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using *HTML* tables, you could use [CSS tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Just set the parent element's display property to `table`. The children elements would then have a display of `table-cell`. The fixed row would obviously have a fixed width and the fluid table cell would fill the remaining space with a width of `100%`. You can use `vertical-align:middle` to vertically center the `.row` elements too.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/)

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row fixed">FIXED..</div>
    <div class="row fluid">FLUID..</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    display:table;
    height:100px;
}
.row {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:0 20px;
}
.row.fixed {
    background: #CCC;
}
.row.fluid {
    background: gold;
    width:100%;
}
```

This approach is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/css-table) with the exception of IE7 and lower.

Comment: I like it, have the advantage of having both colums the same height all the time.

Comment: @NicoO Yep. Plus you can avoid the collapsing issues related to floating elements.

Comment: I need the same height all the time, but do not delete your answer, Nico. Maybe it can help other people! Thank you guys for both answers! :)

Comment: But you were right with the collapsing issue. And with the now attached image it looks like OP wants `vertical-align: middle;` I updated it. Seems a bit antiquated as i think about it...

Answer (score 3):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/Tam7z/1/

This is a very simple way to layout things. But both elements may not be the same height by default. Also you can not verticaly align elements inside of this elements. You should be using a `min-width` for the body or parent item to prevent the fluid div from becoming too small.

```
#left
{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#right
{
    margin-left: 150px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="left">Fixed</div>
<div id="right">Fluid</div>
```